# session-manager plugin on amazon linux 2 not found

Tags: amazon-web-services

Following the docs for installing the session-manager-plugin:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

On Amazon linux 2:

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/session-manager-downloads/plugin/latest/linux_64bit/session-manager-plugin.rpm" -o "session-manager-plugin.rpm"

sudo yum install -y session-manager-plugin.rpm

session-manager-plugin
bash: session-manager-plugin: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is probably not in your path. Try `/usr/local/bin/session-manager-plugin`.